# How to setup rule in ACL file of Hyperledger Composer to validate against enum?

Tags: enums, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Small Subset of my model file is -

```
participant Employee identified by empID {
  o String empID
  o EmployeeCategory category
}

enum EmployeeCategory{ 
  o Internal 
  o External 
}

asset CompanyAsset identified by assetID{
  o String assetID  
  -->  Employee owner
  o String status 
}

transaction AssignStatus{
--> CompanyAsset assetObject 
}
```

Now I want to define a rule in the acl file such that only if the logged in Participant employeeCategory is 'Internal' then allow to create/update the transaction AssignStatus

I was able to do it with the empID field but not for the enum which is what i want

Answer (score 1):

Using your model (with my own namespace) I have these 2 ACL Rules that I think will solve your problem:

```
   rule InternalsOnly {
description: "Allow Internals to submit AssignStatus txn type"
participant(p): "org.acme.trading.Employee"
operation: ALL
resource(v): "org.acme.trading.AssignStatus"
  condition: ( p.category == "Internal" )
action: ALLOW   
}

   rule PreventTransaction {
description: "prevent others executing transactions"
participant: "org.acme.trading.Employee"
operation: ALL
resource: "org.acme.trading.AssignStatus"
action: DENY
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. There is no need for the second rule.. I was using single quotes instead of double quotes for specifying the category and hence was not working on my machine.